# Como sumar un campo de un arraylist - SQL - JAVA

Tags: java, sql

Para el caso, tengo una base de datos con un número de [identificador], el [importe] de esa tupla y algún otro dato sin relevancia. El problema, es que no puedo modificar la BD para calcular los importes desde ahí.

La lógica, recorre con un resultset la BD desde java a la tabla y se añaden a una lista para imprimir los datos.

```
while(rs.next()) {
                        
            String nroCliente = rs.getString(1);
            String moneda = rs.getString(2);
            double importe = rs.getDouble(3);
                            
            linea.add(nroCliente+" "+moneda+" "+importe);
                
            counter++;
        }
```

Lo que quiero hacer, para aquellos nroCliente que sean iguales, sumar el importe y mostrarlo solo una vez con el total.

En vez de mostrar:

999, U$S, 15.00

999, U$S, 20.00

111, U$S,  1.00

123, U$S,  5.00

Quisiera capturar los datos y mostrarlos así:

999, U$S, 35.00

111, U$S,  1.00

123, U$S,  5.00

Cual es la mejor práctica para realizar esta operativa? Si es posible, compartir un ejemplo de código o una solución para un caso similar. Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar la estructura de la tabla de la base de datos?. Requieres hacer un GROUP BY y un SUM en tu consulta de SQL. Pero necesitamos saber la estructura de la tabla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Jacobo, justamente es lo que aclaraba al principio. Los datos con los que puedo trabajar, no es a nivel de consulta BD sino de código. Mediante consulta SQL sería más simple resolver este asunto, pero lo que tengo es el arraylist.

Comment: No necesitas modificar la base de datos. Simplemente hacer la consulta correctamente. Hacer operaciones de consulta en la base de datos no implica alterar la base de datos.

Comment: Estoy operando con un caso puntual de un ambiente limitado, Jacobo. No me refería a alterar literalmente la BD sino que no puedo alterar la consulta del dato crudo que me devuelven de una única tabla.

La situación es, tengo un arraylist que me dvuelve una cadena de lineas como mencionaba arriba. Lo que constultaba, es como comparar de alguna forma durante la captura de datos, un id con el siguiente y sumar importes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de resolver esto es utilizando un `HashMap`. Donde el `nroCliente` es utilizado como la llave para acceder a un objeto auxiliar.

En mi solución creo un objeto auxiliar llamado `Cliente`. Este tiene un método auxiliar para añadir o sumar al importe acumulado del cliente.

```
public class Cliente {
    String nroCliente, moneda;
    double importe;

    public Cliente(String nroCliente, String moneda, double importe) {
        this.nroCliente = nroCliente;
        this.moneda = moneda;
        this.importe = importe;
    }

    public void addImporte(double importe) {
        this.importe += importe;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.nroCliente + " " + this.moneda + " " + this.importe;
    }
}
```

Posteriormente, y antes del ciclo, creo un `HashMap`, en el cual uso el `nroCliente` como llave y un objeto `Cliente` como valor.

```
HashMap<String, Cliente> hashMap = new HashMap()<String, Cliente>();

while(rs.next()) {            
    String nroCliente = rs.getString(1);
    String moneda = rs.getString(2);
    double importe = rs.getDouble(3);

    // Si el hashmap ya tiene dicha llave
    if (hashMap.containsKey(nroCliente)) {
        Cliente c = hashMap.get(nroCliente);
        // Obtener el objecto cliente y sumar al importe
        c.addImporte(importe);
    } else {
        Cliente c = new Cliente(nroCliente, moneda. importe);
        // Crear el cliente y añadirlo al HashMap
        hashMap.put(nroCliente, c);
    }
}
```

Al final, puedes imprimir todos los clientes de la siguiente forma:

```
for (Cliente cliente : hashMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(cliente)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el [identificador] te lo deuvleve ordenado, podrías probar a guardarlo en una variable y hacer que si tienen el mismo identificador los sume, y que cuando tenga uno nuevo empiece a sumar desde 0.

Podrias probar con algo como esto:

```
    double suma = 0;
    string identificador = ""
    while(rs.next()) {
                    
        String nroCliente = rs.getString(1);
        String moneda = rs.getString(2);
        double importe = rs.getDouble(3);
        
        if (identificador.equals(nroCliente)){
            suma += ;
        }else {
            linea.add(nroCliente+" "+moneda+" "+suma);
            identificador = nroCliente;
            suma = importe;
        }
                        
        counter++;
    }
```

Espero tu respuesta,

un saludo

Comment: Hola Maidagan, gracias por tu respuesta. El id, es un número que desconozco y que no me lo devuelven ordenado. Puede ser 60550, 12034, 77890, etc. El problema radica en eso mismo que tu mencionas, no me doy cuenta de cómo puedo comparar el dato actual con la siguiente que guardo en el arraylist.

Lo que pensé en hacer (pero no supe como traducirlo a código) es que mientras voy capturando los datos (tal cual lo planteas en tu ejemplo) ir comparando el rs.getString(1) que tiene el nroCliente con el dato nroCliente que viene a continuación al cumplir con el ciclo. ¿Eso se podría hacer?

Comment: Algo parecido es lo que hace el ejemplo que te he puesto, pero si no viene ordenado no te funcionaría. Puedes probar a crear un HashMap donde guardes el código que te viene y la suma, y comprobar todo el rato a ver si el nuevo código que te viene existe. En tal caso sumar el nuevo importe con el que ya tenía.